# How would I prove that b = c if (andb b c = orb b c) in coq?

Tags: coq, proof, proof-of-correctness

I'm new to coq and I'm trying to prove this...

```
Theorem andb_eq_orb :
  forall (b c : bool),
  (andb b c = orb b c) -> (b = c).
```

Here is my proof, but I get stuck when I get to the goal (false = true -> false = true).

```
Proof.
intros b c.
induction c.
destruct b.
reflexivity.
simpl.
reflexivity.
```

I'm not sure how I would rewrite that expression so I can use reflexivity.  But even if I do that, I'm not sure it will lead to the proof.

I was able to solve the prove if I started with the hypothesis b = c though. Namely...

```
Theorem andb_eq_orb_rev :
  forall (b c : bool),
  (b = c) -> (andb b c = orb b c).
Proof.
intros.
simpl.
rewrite H.
destruct c.
reflexivity.
reflexivity.
Qed.
```

But I can't figure out how to solve if I start with the hypothesis that has boolean functions.

Comment: man its been an extremely long period of time since i did this, but can't you just make it case out on `b` and then use `simpl` and `reflexivity` ? like, hypothesize `b=true` then prove it, then hypothesize `b=false` and prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need induction, since `bool` is not a recursive data structure. Just go through the different cases for the values of `b` and `c`. Use `destruct` to do that.  In two cases the hypothesis `H` will be of the type `true = false`, and you can finish the proof with `inversion H`.  In the other two cases, the goal will be of the type `true = true` and it can be solved with `reflexivity`.

```
Theorem andb_eq_orb : forall b c, andb b c = orb b c -> b = c.
Proof. destruct b,c;  intro H; inversion H; reflexivity. Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best answer.  The inversion tactic seems like he best way to do it. http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Prop.html#lab257

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `intro` tactic.  This will move `false = true` into your proof context as an assumption which you can then use to rewrite.

Comment: Thank you, that helped.  And from there I rewrote with the assumption. `rewrite H. reflexivity.`

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient way to do it.

At the step `induction c.` (where it's stuck):

```
______________________________________(1/2)
b && true = b || true -> b = true
______________________________________(2/2)
b && false = b || false -> b = false
```

You can use `rewrite` and basic theorems in [bool][1] to simplify terms such as `b && true` to `b`, and `b || true` to `true`.

This can reduce it to two "trivial" sub goals:

```
b : bool
______________________________________(1/2)
b = true -> b = true
______________________________________(2/2)
false = b -> b = false
```

This is almost trivial proof using `assumption`, except it is one `symmetry` away. You can `try` if `symmetry` will make them match using:

```
try (symmetry;assumption); try assumption.
```

(Someone who really knows Coq may enlighten me how to `try` this more succinctly)

Putting it together:

```
Require Import Bool.
Theorem andb_eq_orb : forall b c, andb b c = orb b c -> b = c.
Proof. 
destruct c; 

try (rewrite andb_true_r);
try (rewrite orb_true_r);
try (rewrite andb_false_r);
try (rewrite orb_false_r);
intro H;
try (symmetry;assumption); try assumption.
Qed.
```

A second approach is to brute-force it and using the "Truth table" method. This means you can break down all variables to their truth values, and simplify: `destruct b, c; simpl.`. This again gives four trivial implications, up to one `symmetry` to `try`:

```
4 subgoal
______________________________________(1/4)
true = true -> true = true
______________________________________(2/4)
false = true -> true = false
______________________________________(3/4)
false = true -> false = true
______________________________________(4/4)
false = false -> false = false
```

Putting it together:

```
Theorem andb_eq_orb1 : forall b c, andb b c = orb b c -> b = c.
Proof. 
destruct b, c; simpl; intro; try (symmetry;assumption); try assumption.
Qed.
```

The first approach is more troublesome but it does not involve enumerating all truth table rows (I think).

Comment: That's for the help I wasn't aware that I could import and use the theorems from the libraries.

Comment: One question though, if I wasn't to use auto after induction b, how would I resolve the false = true -> false = true?  Since I'm a beginner I want to make sure I understand all the steps that auto is doing.  Also `induction b. auto`. functions differently than `induction b; auto`.  What does the semicolon do?

Comment: Oh, I think I got it.  It was `intro. rewrite H. reflexivity.`

Comment: Just for the record, the bool type is not recursive (only 2 basic constructor, `true` and `false`), so you only need to `destruct b`, using `induction` won't give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
Theorem andb_eq_orb :
  forall (b c : bool),
  (andb b c = orb b c) -> b = c.
  Proof.
    intros b c.
    destruct b as [|].
    - simpl.
      intros H.
      rewrite <- H.
      reflexivity.
    - simpl.
      intros H.
      rewrite -> H.
      reflexivity.
    Qed.
```

Using only `rewrite` and `destruct`.

For some reasons, if I put `intros H` before the `destruct`, `simpl` won't take effect on the introduced `true && c = true || c` part at the first arm.

## Why destruct `b` instead of `c`

Both `andb` and `orb` can only produce an output when the first argument is determined. Destructing `b` enables the following `simpl` to reduce `true && c` to `c` and `true || c` to `true`.

The first arm now looks like this:

```
c = true -> true = c
```

We then rewrite the `true` as `c` at `true = c`. `intros H` represents `c = true` as `H`. `rewrite -> H` tells Coq to rewrite LHS of `H` as the RHS of `H`.

Comment: A plain `simple` affects only the *goal*: to simplify an hypothesis you need e.g. `simple in H`, and to simplify everything, i.e. the goal as well as all hypotheses, you can use `simple in *`.  More details of course in the refman.